# Use of php function in php input type hidden

Tags: php

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='pb1' value='$_POST[pb1]'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='pb2' value='$_POST[pb2]'>";

echo "<input type='hidden' name='pc1' value='$_POST[pc1]'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='pc2' value='$_POST[pc2]'>";
```

I want to perform the above task through a function call like below.

```
function fun1($rm)
{
    for ($i=1;$i<=2;$i++)
    {
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='p.$rm.$i' value='$_POST[p.$rm.$i]'>";
    }
}

fun1('b');
fun1('c');
```

Please suggest how to edit the code inside the function to achieve the goal.

Comment: Just determinate the strings with double quotes if you concatenate variables into your string

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing two techniques here. In PHP, you can use variabled directly in a double quoted string. In a single quoted string you'll have to terminate and concatenate. However, you're also trying to access an array index dynamically within a double quoted string, and that unfortunately wont work. Here's two way to do what you're trying to:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='p$rm$i' value='".$_POST['p'.$rm.$i]."'>";

echo '<input type="hidden" name="p$rm$i" value="'.$_POST['p'.$rm.$i].'">';

// If you weren't accessing the array index dynamically (with a variable) this would work:
echo "<input type='hidden' name='p$rm$i' value='$_POST[pb1]'>";
// note no quotes for the index when inside a string   ^^^
```

Functionally they are exactly the same. Which one to use is really a case of preference. I'd say pick the one you find more readable.